# How can I pick up a value from php to put it into input-element via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I am a pure beginner of Javascript. I got some advanced experience with php but until now I refused to work with JS.

So now I have a question. I wanted to make possible to pickup date-value from a php-generated calendar and put it into a form input field just below of the same page / script.

My idea was to create an onlick-event for each date data. So in my calendar I have this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',$daystamp);
$post = '<div class="cal_day"><a href="#" onclick="dateclick($date)">'.$day.'</a></div>';
```

What I thought to do with Javascript is the following:

```
function dateclick(var x)
{
document.getElementById("date_entry").innerHTML = var x;
}
```

And my html-input field where I like to have the choosen date-values:

```
<input type="text" id="date_entry" name="abs_date" size="15" max-length="15"/>
```

I am sure the solution is simple. At W3Schools I saw that the output of JS doesn't require a return all the time? Should I add it?

Thank you for any answer or help.

**UPDATE:**
So I tried what you mentionned as solution/s:
- I removed the "var" before the x. 
- I have encapsed the $date.

It is still not working. When I look up the element with OPERA it tells me it is a event handler but source file missing. But I have included the functions.js and another function in the same file is working well.
I tried the same thing in the try-field on W3Schools and it worket there.. 
So I guess that there is something in my structure around it that isn't working.

The calendar source line is included above the form element. Is this a problem?

I don't know if I zapped something.

**GOT IT**
The problem was that I needet to put the value into an input element.

The following code works:

```
function dateclick(x)
{
document.getElementById('date_entry').value=x;
return false;
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: which link at W3Schools?

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what exactly is your problem. What should happen, what does happen, what errors do you get...

Comment: You're missing `'`s around `$date` in the `onclick`. But since you are within a `'`-enclosed string, you'll need to escape them: `$post = '<div class="cal_day"><a href="#" onclick="dateclick(\'$date\')">'.$day.'</a></div>';`

Comment: And of course, you need to remove the `var` in your assignment: `document.getElementById("date_entry").innerHTML = x;`

Comment: I tried with x (removed var). It doesn't want to work! Can I do some var_dump to verify if x is really filled with my date variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your php should be:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',$daystamp);
$post = '<div class="cal_day"><a href="#" onclick="dateclick(\''. $date. '\')">'.$day.'</a></div>';
```

And you javascript should be:

```
function dateclick(x)
{
   document.getElementById("date_entry").innerHTML = x;
   return false; // This will force the browser not to load the url.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go through all that trouble, this should work:

```
<script>
    var phpDate = "<?php echo $date; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: He's trying to do a date picker that will insert a date into an input field based on what the user clicks. At least that's what I understood.

Comment: Yes. That wouldn't help me here - the date in the calendar is variable so I need to get the value of the date generated by PHP.